# Umbraco Mediaservice.createmedia for Video

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, umbraco7

I want to create a media object programmatically. Now I was able to create a media entry for an image. But I was wondering how do I do this for video files? I'm trying to search for this but  I got nowhere. I tried using `Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File` but no luck and I'm only getting internal service error saying the media width is missing or something. Below is how I did my Media Creation for an image.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads");

foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{

    using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
        IMedia media = Services.MediaService.CreateMedia(filename, Constants.System.Root, Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image);

        // Set the property value (Umbraco will handle the underlying magic)
        media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, stream);
        Services.MediaService.Save(media);

    }
}
```

Now how do I do this for Videos? Changing the `Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image` to `Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File` didn't work for me

Edit: 
When I try to run using `Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File` and when debugging the code that execute `media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, stream);` is throwing an error and it's expecting to have an umbracoWidth but mediaType.File doesn't have a umbracoWidth property that's why it's throwing an error. How do I override this and let MediaService know that I'm using MediaType.File and it should not look for umbracoWidth property?

Comment: Which specific v7.x version are you on? Google suggests a media bug somewhere in the 7.2.x versions I think. And even if it currently makes no difference, remember to change the media type to file just for good measure,

Comment: @JannikAnker I'm using 7.4.1. I already did change the media type. In my sample I was using Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image and changed it to Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File but I'm still getting an error. Upon executing media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, stream); it throws an error that seems like it's expecting a umbracoWidth but mediatype.file doesn't have any umbracoWidth property

Comment: Kinda dumb, but what if you set umbracoWidth yourself, like you set umbracoFile?

Comment: @JannikAnker hahaha already tried it but it says instance doesn't have a umbracoWidth Property which is weird they also requires it to have umbracoWidth